# Elastic run times - Cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, bosh-deployer, diego

We have two API end points,

One for development environment - `a.b.c.org.cloud`

Another for POConcept environment - `x.y.x.org.cloud`

We use [apps mgr](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/console/manage-apps.html), to view an API end point, that has its own organisation and space.

---

Each elastic runtime has diego cells running containers(garden) that host an application instance.

---

From the bosh automation of VM instances aspect,

1) Can I say that, each API end point  have their own elastic run time ?

2) Is the route name of an app supposed to be unique across elastic runtimes? To avoid such [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54580831/3317808)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Can I say that, each API end point have their own elastic run time ?

Yes, I guess you could say that. Each API represents a unique foundation or installation of CF.

> 2) Is the route name of an app supposed to be unique across elastic runtimes? To avoid such errors

Yes. If you have two foundations, you can have the same route for an app in each foundation. I'm not sure it's a common scenario, but there are reasons you might want to do that.

For example, if I have a domain `example.com` and I map the route `www.example.com` to an example `my-cool-app`. I can do that on both foundations.

I can then control which app running in two different foundations receives traffic by simply adjusting DNS. You could have all traffic to one of the foundations (perhaps having the other as a hot-spare) or you could split it across the two (perhaps to have more capacity or to route requests to facilities that are geographically closer to users).

That said, you *must* have a unique system domain for each foundation. This is the domain that's used by the API & other services like UAA, Apps Manager, etc... It's also advised that your apps domain, the default domain used apps on the foundation also be unique.

You can add as many additional domains as you like those and those can happily overlap foundations.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You are mentioning the term *two foundations*. I did not understand.. if each foundation an elastic runtime.

Comment: Each API represents a unique foundation? Is `a.b.c.org.cloud` an installation of cloudfoundry separate from installation for `x.y.z.org.cloud`?

Comment: Am confused with your two answers... my understanding is... there is one bosh infra component that creates these two elastic runtimes on two different logical switch es. So, my understanding is, two elastic runtimes within single cloud foundry installation.

Comment: Cloud contoller database(CCDB) will be common to both elastic runtimes. CCDB maintains app:route information for each app. Is that correct?

Comment: The term "foundation" commonly refers to one installation of Cloud Foundry.

Comment: `my understanding is... there is one bosh infra component that creates these two elastic runtimes on two different logical switch es.` -> most commonly no. You have two entirely separate foundations. That said there is a concept of "isolation segments" which can roughly do what you're asking. You share some common parts like Cloud Controller & UAA, but have separate Gorouter & Cells.