# "You are not authorized to perform the requested action cf route sharing" while setup of route sharing

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to share a route between 2 spaces to avoid downtime while moving an app from a space (`originspace`) into another space (`otherspace`).
We're using SAP BTP Cloud Foundry runtime for the app

I found the process at
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#share-route

```bash
cf target -o orgname-s originspace
cf8 enable-feature-flag route_sharing
cf8 share-route example.com --hostname exampleroutehost -s otherspace -o orgname
```

But I get the following message

> Enabling feature flag route_sharing as myemail@example.com...
>
> You are not authorized to perform the requested action
>
> FAILED
>
> Sharing route exampleroutehost .example.com to space otherspace as myemail@example.com
>
> Feature Disabled: route_sharing
>
> FAILED

I already have the role `ORG_MANAGER` and `ORG_AUDITOR` for the organization and spaces.
I have also checked that Cloud Foundry only has some privileges for the admin user but it either doesn't exist for BTP or I don't have access to it.

I tried checking which feature flags I have enabled

```bash
$ cf8 feature-flags
Getting feature flags as myemail@example.com...

name                                          state
app_bits_upload                               enabled
app_scaling                                   enabled
diego_docker                                  enabled
env_var_visibility                            enabled
hide_marketplace_from_unauthenticated_users   disabled
private_domain_creation                       enabled
resource_matching                             enabled
route_creation                                enabled
route_sharing                                 disabled
service_instance_creation                     enabled
service_instance_sharing                      enabled
set_roles_by_username                         enabled
space_developer_env_var_visibility            enabled
space_scoped_private_broker_creation          enabled
task_creation                                 enabled
unset_roles_by_username                       enabled
user_org_creation                             disabled
```

Please tell me how to access to the user admin or how to enable route sharing